# How to prevent $() from being executed prematurely when creating an alias

Tags: bash, alias

I'm using Atom as a text editor, but don't like its fuzzy search, so I'm trying to configure an alternative. I found a nice command line fuzzy search (fzf) that works nicely like this:

`atom $(fzf)`

When I put this in my .bash_profile, like so :

`alias atm="atom $(fzf)"`

The `fzf` command runs prematurely, as soon as the .bash_profile is loaded. How can I defer the execution of `fzf` until I run the `atm` alias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use single quotes to prevent expansion at the time of assignment:

```
alias atm='atom $(fzf)'
```